# Where to download Blacklight WPFControls 4.2

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, silverlight, controls

Where can I download the Blacklight WPFControls v4.2?

Also, can anyone tell me why Blacklight.Controls.dll is dependent upon the WPFToolkit?  There isn't even a reference to it in the project.  Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Has anyone found Blacklight wpf controls v4.2 ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349703/has-anyone-found-blacklight-wpf-controls-v4-2)

Comment: Not a duplicate, see post below. Also, that post is over a year old.

Comment: Maybe this is the correct version: https://bpm2.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Blacklight.Controls/

Comment: Hmm that link doesn't seem to work in a browser and through SVN I'm getting "handshake failed, connection truncated".  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is available on [**codeplex**](http://blacklight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/2675).  You could probably download it and compile.  Looks like the last change was just a few days ago.

Comment: That's version 4.1... It requires WPFToolkit which blows up in a .net 4 project.  This is why I asked for 4.2.

Comment: I have not had time to dl it and build it.  Some comments on previous changesets only say 4.4.  Is that in fact version 4.4?

Comment: Either way those are the controls for silverlight.  They don't contain the WPFControls, which is what I really need.  I have an older version of the Blacklight.WPFControls, but as I said, it requires WPFToolkit and thus I can't use it in a .NET 4.0 project as the WPFToolkit conflicts with .NET 4.0 namespaces.  Thanks anyways!

Comment: As an aside, I've tried editting the WPFToolkit to change the namespaces of the conflicting ones, I've also tried editing the Blacklight.WPFControls to remove the depenency on the WPFToolkit but I haven't been successful thus far.  I don't even see where it is referenced in the sourcecode.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!